# 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

Tags: c++, mfc, boost-thread

My problem is:

`Error  1   error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\afxwin.h    1991    1   ProcessInfo`

And my code:

```
boost::thread timerThread(&CMainFunctions::TimerFunction, this, pid, TIMER_INTERVAL_MS, lstBox);
```

`lstBox` is MFC ListBox., my TimerFunction is:

```
void CMainFunctions::TimerFunction(int pid, int interval, CListBox &lstbox)
```

What I need to do, to edit my MFC form, or rather edit my ListBox in my form in thread?

Comment: Have you tried passing the listbox as e.g. `boost::ref(lstBox)`?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments supplied to the [`boost::thread`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor) constructor are copied. From the linked reference page:

> As if thread(boost::bind(f,a1,a2,...)). **Consequently, f and each an are copied into internal storage for access by the new thread.**

The compiler is complaining that an attempt is made to copy a non-copyable object. As suggested in a comment by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) to the question use [`boost::ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/ref.html) to prevent the copy and pass a reference to the argument instead. The argument passed by reference must exist for the lifetime of thread.